# Dependency header can not be included in a header file if added with PRIVATE include_directory and link_library

Tags: c++, cmake

First of all,sorry if this is a duplicate question. I am newbie in c++ and cmake both so bear with me. I couldn't find anything I could understand regarding this problem though I am not entirely sure I was able to search correctly.

I am trying to build a static library and trying to use [cpr](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr). When I do `target_include_directories PRIVATE` and `target_link_libraries PRIVATE` like below i can not include `cpr.h` in header files. It can be included on source files though. If I change one of them (doesn't matter which one) `PUBLIC`, it can be included in headers too. What is the reason behind this?

Project structure

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── external
│   └── cpr
├── request.h
├── spider.cpp
├── spider.h
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── external
    ├── request_tests.cpp
    └── test.cpp
```

Top-level (relevant) CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(scrapp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(external/cpr)
set(SCRAPP_SOURCES
        spider.cpp request.h
        request.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SCRAPP_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/cpr/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE cpr::cpr)
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

edit: The main problem is building the library fails, not a project that depends on it. I can't use `cpr` in the library (target which is linked PRIVATE ly) itself. I can use `cpr` headers in `spider.cpp` but can't use in `spider.h` or `request.h` in the same project.

Comment: @drescherjm But I can't use them in the target (library I'm building) itself. I can use `cpr` headers in `spider.cpp` but can't use in `spider.h` or `request.h` in the same project.

Comment: Am I confused are you saying that with `PRIVATE` building `scrapp` fails because it can't use headers from `cpr` from other headers in the SCRAPP_SOURCES?

Comment: Yes, building `scrapp` fails.

Comment: I deleted my comments. someone else will have to answer. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I edited to question to be more clear.

Comment: In modern cmake this line is obsolete: `target_include_directories.(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/cpr/include)` since `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cpr::cpr)` should address that. Assuming `cpr` is done properly.